# Sort a stream descending number

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a list that which looks like this: `[3 : [Reasonable product ], 5 : [Great ]]`
I want to sort (using streams) this list by the number before `:`.
The list it has to look like this:
`[5 : [Great ], 3 : [Reasonable product ]]`
My code looks like this:
`return ratingsForProduct.stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());`
I don't know how to use lambda function or what I have to put as parameter to sorted().

Comment: Do you mean you have a map? Or is ```3: [Reasonable product ]``` a string?

Comment: `3: [Reasonable product ]` is a string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass the custom [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) to sort descending order by extracting integer from every string

```
List<String> sortedList = list.stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.<String>comparingInt(s->Integer.parseInt(s.split(":")[0].trim())).reversed())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or you can also use [Collections.sort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-java.util.Comparator-)

```
Collections.sort(list,Comparator.<String>comparingInt(s->Integer.parseInt(s.split(":")[0].trim())).reversed());
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can be sure of the format of list items, you can write your own comparator:

```java
Collections.sort(ratingsForProduct, (a, b) -> {
    return Integer.parseInt(b.substring(0, b.indexOf(':'))) -
           Integer.parseInt(a.substring(0, a.indexOf(':')));
});
```

We use `substring(0, indexOf(':'))` instead of `charAt(0)` to handle values greater than 10. If you wanted to sort in ascending order, you would change the comparator to substract b from a (instead of a from b as it is currently).

Answer (score 1):

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(
        List.of("3 : [Reasonable product ]", "5 : [Great ]"));
```

The comparator simply parses the number at the start of the string until a space is encountered.  This will work for any size number within the range of an integer.  You can use a stream or `Collections.sort()`;

```
Comparator<String> comp = Comparator.comparing(
        a -> Integer.valueOf(a.substring(0,a.indexOf(" "))),
        Comparator.reverseOrder());

list = list.stream().sorted(comp)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(list);
```

prints

```
[5 : [Great ], 3 : [Reasonable product ]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's inefficient to convert a string to an integer each time strings are compared.

Try this.

```
List<String> result = list.stream()
    .map(string -> new Object() {
        int key = Integer.valueOf(string.substring(0, string.indexOf(":")).trim());
        String value = string;
    })
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(obj -> obj.key, Comparator.reverseOrder()))
    .map(obj -> obj.value)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or

```
List<String> result = list.stream()
    .map(string -> Map.entry(Integer.valueOf(string.substring(0, string.indexOf(":")).trim()), string))
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Entry::getKey, Comparator.reverseOrder()))
    .map(Entry::getValue)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```